# How do I configure AWS network load balancers to route HTTPS traffic with Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-elb

I am trying to use API Gateway’s VPC links to route traffic to an internal API on HTTPS. 
But, VPC links forces me to change my API’s load balancer from "application" to "network".

I understand that the network load balancer is on layer 4 and as such will not know about HTTPS.

I am used to using the layer 7 application load balancer. As such, I am not sure how I should configure or indeed use the network load balancer in terraform.

Below is my attempt at configuring the network load balancer in Terraform. 
The health check fails and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" “app” {
  name = "${var.env}-${var.subenv}-${var.appname}"
  cluster = "${aws_ecs_cluster.cluster.id}"
  task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.app.arn}"
  desired_count = "${var.desired_app_count}"
  deployment_minimum_healthy_percent = 50
  deployment_maximum_percent = 200
  iam_role = "arn:aws:iam::${var.account}:role/ecsServiceRole"

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = "${aws_lb_target_group.app-lb-tg.arn}"
    container_name = "${var.env}-${var.subenv}-${var.appname}"
    container_port = 9000
  }
  depends_on = [
    "aws_lb.app-lb"
  ]
}

resource "aws_lb" “app-lb" {
  name               = "${var.env}-${var.subenv}-${var.appname}"
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "network"
  subnets = "${var.subnet_ids}"
  idle_timeout = 600

  tags {
    Owner = ""
    Env = "${var.env}"
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" “app-lb-listener" {
  load_balancer_arn = "${aws_lb.app-lb.arn}"
  port = 443
  protocol = "TCP"

  default_action {
    type = "forward"
    target_group_arn = "${aws_lb_target_group.app-lb-tg.arn}"
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" “app-lb-tg" {
  name = "${var.env}-${var.subenv}-${var.appname}"
  port = 443
  stickiness = []

  health_check {
    path = "/actuator/health"
  }

  protocol = "TCP"
  vpc_id = "${var.vpc_id}"
}
```

For reference, this is how I previously configured my application load balancer before attempting to switch to a network load balancer:

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "app" {
  name = "${var.env}-${var.subenv}-${var.appname}"
  cluster = "${aws_ecs_cluster.cluster.id}"
  task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.app.arn}"
  desired_count = "${var.desired_app_count}"
  deployment_minimum_healthy_percent = 50
  deployment_maximum_percent = 200
  iam_role = "arn:aws:iam::${var.account}:role/ecsServiceRole"

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = "${aws_lb_target_group.app-alb-tg.arn}"
    container_name = "${var.env}-${var.subenv}-${var.appname}"
    container_port = 9000
  }
  depends_on = [
    "aws_alb.app-alb"]
}

resource "aws_alb" "app-alb" {
  name = "${var.env}-${var.subenv}-${var.appname}"
  subnets = "${var.subnet_ids}"
  security_groups = [
    "${var.vpc_default_sg}",
    "${aws_security_group.app_internal.id}"]
  internal = false
  idle_timeout = 600
  tags {
    Owner = ""
    Env = "${var.env}"
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "app-alb-listener" {
  load_balancer_arn = "${aws_alb.app-alb.arn}"
  port = "443"
  protocol = "HTTPS"
  ssl_policy = "ELBSecurityPolicy-2015-05"
  certificate_arn = "${var.certificate_arn}"

  default_action {
    type = "forward"
    target_group_arn = "${aws_lb_target_group.app-alb-tg.arn}"
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "app-alb-tg" {
  name = "${var.env}-${var.subenv}-${var.appname}"
  port = 80
  health_check {
    path = "/actuator/health"
  }
  protocol = "HTTP"
  vpc_id = "${var.vpc_id}"   
}
```

Comment: Does that apply out okay or does it error? If it doesn't error is it just that the health check is failing? That looks like AWS should fail it on validation when you apply it (would be tricky for Terraform to do it because it doesn't officially support cross parameter validation) but you shouldn't be specifying a health check path without setting the health check protocol to HTTP/HTTPS.

Comment: Check this link out https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-tls-termination-for-network-load-balancers/

If I remember correctly you need to change from TCP to TLS for "Protocol"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A network load balancer [automatically performs passive health checks on non UDP traffic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/target-group-health-checks.html) that flows through it so if that's enough then you can just remove the active health check configuration.

If you want to enable active health checks then you can either use TCP health checks (the default) which will just check that the port is open or you can specify the HTTP/HTTPS protocol and specify a path. Ideally the AWS API would error when you try to specify a path for the health check but don't set the protocol to HTTP or HTTPS but apparently that's not the case right now.

With Terraform this would look something like this:

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "app-alb-tg" {
  name     = "${var.env}-${var.subenv}-${var.appname}"
  port     = 443
  protocol = "TCP"
  vpc_id   = "${var.vpc_id}"

  health_check {
    path     = "/actuator/health"
    protocol = "HTTPS"
  }
}
```

Remember that active health checks which will check that the port is open on the target from the network load balancer's perspective (not just the source traffic).  This means that your target will need to allow traffic from the subnets that your NLBs reside in as well as security groups or CIDR ranges etc that your source traffic originates in.

Comment: When I try this with TCP aws_lb_listener, I get this error: "The listener and the following target groups have incompatible protocols".

Comment: Sorry, copy pasted the wrong target group definition you have. Was meant to be just a change to the health check protocol on the target group so you should still be passing TCP traffic through to your targets but using the HTTP or HTTPS protocol for health checks.

Comment: Np, One thing I'm not so sure about is where the ssl_policy and certificate_arn should go. As in the previous ALB I set this in aws_lb_listener. But given I am now using a NLB am I right to assume they are no longer needed?

Comment: You would only need the `ssl_policy` and `certificate_arn` if you were offloading TLS at the NLB instead of doing passthrough TCP which is what you have in your question. If you're having a specific issue with that configuration though you'd be better off creating a separate question.